# display grade lowest and highest

Tags: java, arrays

How do I display the highest and lowest average grade?
I tried other solutions but it's not working

Can you help how to display the highest average grade and the lowest average

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);
    int numStud, numGrade = 0, count = 0, count2 = 0;

    double totalgrades = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter number of students:");
    numStud = console.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter number of student grades:");
    numGrade = console.nextInt();
    String[] students = new String [numStud];
    double [][] grades = new double [numStud][numGrade];
    double[] average = new double[numStud];
    String x = console.nextLine();

    System.out.println("");
    while(count<numStud)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter name of student " + (count + 1) + ":");
        students[count] = console.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter " + numGrade + " grades:");
        while(count2<numGrade)
        {
            grades[count][count2] = console.nextDouble();
            totalgrades = totalgrades + grades [count][count2];
            count2++;

        }
        average[count] = totalgrades / numGrade;
        totalgrades = 0;
        String y = console.nextLine();
        count2 = 0;
        count++;



}
count = 0;
count2 = 0;
while(count<numStud)
{
    System.out.println("The grades of " + students[count] + " are:");
    while(count2<numGrade)
    {
        System.out.println(grades[count][count2] + " ");
        count2++;
    }
    System.out.println("The average is " + average[count] + ".");
    System.out.println("");
    count2 = 0;
    count++;        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose all average grades keeps in `average` array. Then,

```
Arrays.sort(average);
System.out.print("min = " + average[0] + ", max = " + average[average.length - 1]);
```

To fill `average` you have to:

```
for(int j = 0; j < grades.length; ++j) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < grades[j].length; ++i) sum += grades[j][i];

    average[j] = sum / numGrade;
}
```

Filling `grades` array you have done correctly. But I advise you to turn the `while` loop into the `for` loop.

Comment: @AliceManalangLacanilao, you shouldn't *create a new bicycle*, just using standard `Arrays.sort` does all for you

Answer (score 0):

To find the ***highest***:

- Set a variable say `max` as the first element (or 0)
- Loop though the entire array
- Compare the value of each array element against `max`
- If element value > `max`
- Update `max` with element's value
- At end of loop you will get maximum value of the array.

  ```
  int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
  for(int x=0; x<average.length; x++)
      if(average[x] > max)
          max = average[x];
  ```

---

To find the ***lowest***:

- Set a variable say `min` as the first element (or 0)
- Loop though the entire array
- Compare the value of each array element against `min`
- If element value < `min`
- Update `min` with element's value
- At end of loop you will get minimum value of the array.

  ```
  int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
  for(int x=0; x<average.length; x++)
      if(average[x] < min)
          min = average[x];
  ```

Comment: can you trying sending the code? i'm just new in java and i dont really get it thank you very much :)))

Comment: @AliceManalangLacanilao Just updated. With the explanation, it should be easy to follow. Let me know if it solves you problem.

Comment: finding the highest work but finding the lowest the output is always 0? what's wrong with it? i really appreciate you helping me thank you very much :000

Comment: @AliceManalangLacanilao show me your codes, I believe there is a typo error in your codes. Did you set `min` as `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and **not** `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. ??

Comment: int max = 0;
for( count=0; count<average.length; count++)
    if(average[count] > max)
        max = (int) average[count];
       
        System.out.println("the highest average is : " + max);
        
    
      
int min = 0;
for( count2=0; count2<average.length; count2++)
    if(average[count2] < min)
        min = (int) average[count2];
        System.out.println("The lowest average is : " + min);

Comment: @AliceManalangLacanilao For getting the minimum. ***Use*** `int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;`. ***Not*** `int min = 0;`

Comment: @AliceManalangLacanilao you can only accept one solution. Accept the one which helped you most....